# Do someone know how to use this 8 GB space in ny computer?

Tags: windows, disk-space, computer-architecture

I have same thing from a long time. I want to extend this 8.31 GB to c or d any drive. I tried but I got a error. see reference image.

Do someone know how to do this in windows.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried GParted? Grab the live disk, boot from it and you should be able to add that 8GB to one of your drives.

Comment: What do the actual partitions look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the green partition is an extended partition, in which the C: drive lives along with that 8GB space.

To make use of that space, you would have to move the C: drive to a new partition, which means cloning the data and putting it into a new primary partition.

Alternatively, some tools (free or for pay) will allow you to move the C: partition to take up the entire extended partition, but since this involves moving data, it would have to be an offline process.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this in Windows, as windows can not move a mounted and running partition, the same as most operating systems. As you are trying to move your C: drive in which windows is actually installed this make it impossible, as you can not unmount your running windows installation.

As the free space is part of an extend partition, you can not add that to your D: drive either as the portioning scheme does not allow for those type of operations. With your current running operating system in the extended partition you would not be able to unmout it to resize your extend partitions.

You would have to boot up into an other operating system to move the partition. The simplest would be to download a Linux live disk http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php/. This disk boots up into a nice simple GUI that allows you to make changes to your partition structures.

Follow the many tutorials on the internet that explain who to move/ resize a partition.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions/
https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/resize-partition-with-gparted

You should run a windows CHKDISK before and after the partition resize to be able to boot up into a working windows install.

**You should always have a back up of this partition and any important data, making changes to your partition table can make all your data irrecoverable.**